# Dynamically localize bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, localization, datetimepicker

I'm trying to localize the [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php) which has a folder 'locales' that contains the different languages.

This picker has an option called 'language'. I simply placed behind it 'nl' to see what that will do. This of course didn't work because the language 'nl' is defined in a different file.

Copying the 'nl' language from the file located in the 'locales' into the "bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" file did the trick. Right behind the 'en'-block:

```
var dates = $.fn.datetimepicker.dates = {
        en: {
            days:        ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            daysShort:   ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
            daysMin:     ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
            months:      ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            meridiem:    ["am", "pm"],
            suffix:      ["st", "nd", "rd", "th"],
            today:       "Today"
        },
        nl: {
            days: ["Zondag", "Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag", "Zondag"],
            daysShort: ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za", "Zo"],
            daysMin: ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za", "Zo"],
            months: ["Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
            monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mrt", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"],
            today: "Vandaag",
            suffix: [],
            meridiem: []
        }
    };
```

My question is, is there a way to load the file containing the desired language instead of putting all those languages in the js file like I did here for the 'nl' language?

**EDIT**

```
function setLanguage() {
        //debugger;
        // Let's get the browser's language
        var l_lang;
        if (navigator.userLanguage) // Explorer
            l_lang = navigator.userLanguage;
        else if (navigator.language) // FF
            l_lang = navigator.language;
        else
            l_lang = "";

        // If the parameter passed is not a string or an array, 
        // or if no browser's language can be found, let's use default file.
        if (l_lang == "") {
            loadScript("Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js");
            return;
        }

        var browserLang = l_lang.substr(0, 2);

        if (browserLang != "" || browserLang != null) {
            loadScript("Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker." + browserLang + ".js");
            loadScript("Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js");
            return;
        }

        // If no language found, let's load the default language file:
        loadScript("Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js");
    };

    // A simple function to dynamically load a script.
    // Please note it uses jQuery (but you can adapt it easily)!
    function loadScript(url) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url;
        $("head").append(script);
        return;
    };
```

And in the view (ASP.NET-MVC) where I'm using the `datetimepicker`:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var browserLang;

    if (navigator.userLanguage) // Explorer
        browserLang = navigator.userLanguage.substr(0, 2);
    else if (navigator.language) // FF
        browserLang = navigator.language.substr(0, 2);
    else
        browserLang = 'en';

    $('#dpk1').datetimepicker({
        format: "dd M yyyy - hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        minuteStep: 15,
        startView: 2,
        todayHighlight: true,
        language: browserLang,
        pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
    });

    $('#dpk2').datetimepicker({
        format: "dd M yyyy - hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        minuteStep: 15,
        startView: 2,
        todayHighlight: true,
        language: browserLang,
        pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
    });
 });
```

Comment: you must load the js language file before initialize datetimepicker, then it should be fine

Comment: The 'nl' was just an example, any language the user has set in his browser options (if supported) should be an option in the application. This needs to be dynamically set. So how exactly would that work? I'm updating my question with my approach which I tried.

Comment: `loadScript("Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker." + browserLang + ".js");` should be load after datatimepicker plugin but before initializing the datetimepicker element. You should try that!  See DOC: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php#i18n

Comment: Just checking your code, your logic seems to fail for loading script because you are loading datetimepicker more than once. Here: `if (browserLang != "" || browserLang != null)` you already load datetimepicker plugin inside this IF statement and reload it just after anyway

Comment: The first IF contains a return; So loading it again after would be a bug in jquery.

Comment: Which bug? You can load same file as many time you wish only the previous one will be overwritten. You should try removing this line(s): `// If no language found, let's load the default language file:
        loadScript("Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js");` And load language file after plugin, not before as you are currently doing

Comment: Your solution worked, had to switch those loadscript lines with each other. However, I can't mark this question as answered.

Comment: I was referring to your third comment about loading the  datetimepicker again and you mentioned this line: `if (browserLang != "" || browserLang != null)`. But there is a `return` statement in it so it wont continue executing the code in this function.

Comment: You are correct, i didn't see it, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [DOC](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php#i18n):

> The plugin supports i18n for the month and weekday names and the
>   weekStart option. The default is English ('en'); other available
>   translations are avilable in the js/locales/ directory, simply include
>   your desired locale after the plugin. To add more languages, simply
>   add a key to $.fn.datetimepicker.dates, before calling
>   .datetimepicker().

Comment: Have to say that I did what the doc said. Think i needed to clear my cache as I've tried a few other things which might still have been in my cache, and messed it up. Thanks!